# How to implement CollectionView for a slide show with prominent looking levels in iOS?

Tags: ios, ios-autolayout

I have an image slideshow where first image is prominent while previous and next image will appear back of current image?

Something like

[image: sample]

Also with the page control bubbles ?

Comment: You should use iCarousel https://github.com/nicklockwood/iCarousel

Comment: ok gr8 :) , but how will i add the page controller bubbles ?